# Flutter/Dart json encode passwords with special characters

Tags: flutter, dart, http-post, html-escape-characters

I am new to programming and aworking with Flutter. I am trying to login to an API using a post request.

The  Model (used app.quicktype.io)

```
import 'dart:convert';

class UserLogin {
  UserLogin({
    this.login,
    this.password,
    this.entity,
    this.reset,
  });

  String login;
  String password;
  String entity;
  int reset;

  factory UserLogin.fromRawJson(String str) =>
      UserLogin.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory UserLogin.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserLogin(
        login: json["login"],
        password: json["password"],
        entity: json["entity"],
        reset: json["reset"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "login": login,
        "password": password,
        "entity": entity,
        "reset": reset,
      };
}



String loginJason = json.encode(
        UserLogin(login: login, password: password, entity: "", reset: 0));
```

The request:

```
static Future apiLogin(
   String url, String login, String password, String loginJason) async {
        var response = await http.post(url,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: loginJason);
```

the body of the request should look like this:

```
{"login":"login", 
  "password":"password",
  "entity": "",
  "reset" 0
}
```

Everything works fine until a special character used in the password e.g "123@abc" then dart encodes the body like this:

```
{"login":"login", 
 "password":"123%40abc",
 "entity": "",
 "reset" 0
}
```

The password is no longer valid because is has been reformatted (Html-Escape). How do I prevent reformatting of the password.

Answer (score 1):

Uri.decodeComponent("123%40abc") = 123@abc

Answer (score 0):

Most Of the Problem with # or @ Character if you want to Sent # or @ related String to Server using Http (Flutter) You Can Do This :

```
 Uri.encodeComponent("example@#");
```

To Get Data From Server  Use :

```
Uri.decodeComponent("example@#");
```

Mainly Uri encoding/decoding Needed for Special Character